# Взаимодействие с javascript на Андроид

Tags: webview, javascript, java, android, json

Всем добрый день.
В процессе разработки приложения встала необходимость реализации взаимодействия с `javascript` функциями встроенными в Web-страницу. Пример разработки гибридного приложения нашел по следующей [ссылке](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/x-andbene2/)
Далее переделал представленный в примере код под свои нужды следующим образом:

```
public class AndroidJSON extends Activity {
    private WebView browser = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.calculator);
        browser.setWebViewClient(new wvClient());
        WebSettings settings = browser.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        browser.clearCache(true);
        browser.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        browser.addJavascriptInterface(new CalculatorHandler(), "calc");
        browser.loadUrl("http://ofs.ft-ru.ru/table_android/1");

    }

    final class wvClient extends WebViewClient {
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            browser.loadUrl("javascript:startup()");
        }
    }

    final class CalculatorHandler {

        public void Info(String str) {
            Log.i("Calc", str.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Hello from Ivan",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Данные изменения прекрасно работают в том проекте который я скачал. Далее я данный код копирую в свой проект и там он не работает. Не понимаю причины, и по тихоньку начинаю сходить с ума!

Версия АПИ - совпадает, версия java компилятора(1.6) - совпадает. Код также вынесен в отдельный класс, на лайоут также только WebView.

В моем проекте страница по ссылке грузится, но ни одна javascript функция не работает. При вызове функции возникает следующая ошибка:

```
10-14 13:21:32.929: E/Web Console(6995): Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'Info' at http://ofs.ft-ru.ru/table_android/1:118
```

Не могу понять причины!

Помогите пожалуйста!

Заранее всем спасибо!

UPD: Убрал в манифесте следующее:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
```

Но проект превратился(по крайней мере на эмуляторе) в античеловеческое вторение, в плане расстановки элементов!

Comment: Покажите ещё, как происходит вызов метода на стороне JS.

Comment: Он работает. http://ofs.ft-ru.ru/table_android/1, посмотрите нажав на любой кнопке проинспектировать элемент!

Comment: Сделал! Работает!!! Огромное спасибо! А теоритечки в чем была причина. То есть надо чтобы компилятор об этом знал? А если в манифесте не прописанны версии АПИ, то компилятору по барабану, так что ли получается?

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте пометить класс `CalculatorHandler` аннотацией `@JavascriptInterface`.

Читаем в [документации](http://goo.gl/Vhb3a) на метод `addJavascriptInterface`:

> **public void addJavascriptInterface (Object object, String name)**
>
> Injects the supplied Java object into this WebView. The object is injected into the JavaScript context of the main frame, using the supplied name. This allows the Java object's methods to be accessed from JavaScript. **For applications targeted to API level JELLY_BEAN_MR1 and above, only public methods that are annotated with JavascriptInterface can be accessed from JavaScript.** For applications targeted to API level JELLY_BEAN or below, all public methods (including the inherited ones) can be accessed, see the important security note below for implications.

Comment: Спасибо! Действительно помогло!